# Maxima: How to turn all coefficients of a polynomial positive

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

For a maths project I am currently using the CAS Maxima (wxMaxima). As the project is almost finished I would like to remain with Maxima, but there is one problem left:

The issue is that I have to convert a certain polynomial P by making all its coefficients positive. I.e. adding up the absolutes of all coefficients (but not taking the absolute value of the whole polynomial), for example

```
P(...)=-15x^3+3y^2-4x^2
```

turns to

```
P'(...)=15x^3+3y^2+4x^2
```

I could not find an implemented function that would help me with this. And could not find a solution by implementing it with a map function. Do you know a way to solve this issue?

Thank you for your help!
Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate a sum of absolute values:

```
P:-15*x^3+3*y^2-4*x^2;
P2:sum(abs(args(P)[i]),i,1,length(args(P)));
>> 3*y^2+15*x^2*abs(x)+4*x^2
```

(unfortunately, here is abs(x) but you can use `subst(x,abs(x),P2)`)

The same with map:

```
P2:map(abs,P);
```

Or convert an expresstion to string and replace "-" to "+":

```
s:string(P);
s2:ssubst("+","-",s);
P2:eval_string(s2);
>> 3*y^2+15*x^3+4*x^2
```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution did not help, as Maxima also took unnecessary absolutes of some variables (what I did not intend). But converting P to a String finally helped out.